# What is the maximum size of the database created in SQL Server 2008 R2? and Is it varies on Harddisk size?

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE DATABASE MYDB

USE MYDB
```

My question is what is the maximum size that can accommodate in the `MYDB` database .?

Comment: Yes..I got it @BAdmin..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at

[Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> Database size:
>
> 524,272 terabytes

Answer (score 0):

Maximum database size can be 524,272 terabytes in Enterprise edition. Note that a single data file can exceed 16 TB.

Answer (score 0):

Database size maximum size is `524,272 terabytes`

check here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/07/24/60267.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server Express edition maximum database size is 10 GB.